# What's the difference between using the "self." prefix and writing "self" in the capture list of a closure?

Tags: swift, closures

I was writing some code similar to:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    var foo = "foo"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default, handler: { _ in
            print(foo)
        }))
    }
}
```

Xcode reports an error at `print(foo)` that I forgot to capture `self`, and suggests *two* fixes.:

1. `print(self.foo)`, or;
2. Add a capture list of `[self]` to the closure: `... handler: { [self] _ in ...`

Now, I remember that before Xcode 12/Swift 5.3, it didn't use to do that. It either gives no fixes, or just the first one.

My question is, what's the difference between these two fixes? Do they somehow capture `self` in a different way?

The [Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID546) seems to touch on this a little bit, but doesn't seem to say what the difference between them is.

Comment: Just reading from the language guide: "Here’s a version of doSomething() that captures self by including it in the closure’s capture list, and then refers to self implicitly" (in contrast to the 1 or 2 sentences before it) - implies that capturing `[self]` allows one to write an escaping closure referring the self implicitly throughout (vs having to write it explicitly). So, seems like it's a matter of preference

Comment: Just for the record, this is a new feature implemented in Swift v5.3: [SE-0269](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0269-implicit-self-explicit-capture.md) - Increase availability of implicit `self` in `@escaping` closures when reference cycles are unlikely to occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are functionally the same, both explicitly capturing `self`. The `[self]` pattern avoids having to litter the closure with repeated `self.` references if you had multiple property and/or method references. But they both do precisely the same thing, capturing `self`.

As that document you reference says:

> Normally, a closure captures variables implicitly by using them in the body of the closure, but in this case you need to be explicit. If you want to capture `self`, write `self` explicitly when you use it, or include `self` in the closure’s capture list.

Bottom line, they’re the same thing.

---

For what it’s worth, the other option is to avoid capturing `self` altogether. E.g. you might only capture `foo`:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default) { [foo] _ in
    print(foo)
})
```